# Image not showing and uploading in the text editor - CKEditor in Strapi headless CMS

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, editor, strapi, rich-text-editor

I am using Strapi as CMS for blog and using CKeditor for rich-text-editor.

What I want -

1. I want the image uploaded from CKeditor to be uploaded in the AWS S3 Bucket
2. I want this image to show in the CKeditor - text editor

I tried to google it and tried various configurations but not successful.

Thank you in advance.